# What exactly is the eigenspace of a graph (in spectral clustering)?

Tags: graphs, clustering, linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-analysis

When we find the eigenvectors of a graph (say in the context of spectral clustering), what exactly is the vector space involved here? Of what vector space (or eigenspace) are we finding the eigenvalues of?

Comment: Well, I am not really familiar with these clustering algorithms, but aren't you actually finding the eigenvectors of matrices such as the adjacency or similarity matrices of the graph? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix.

Comment: Yes we are, but these adjacency matrices are transformations from one vector space to another. I wanted to know if there exists any interpretation of either this  transformation or the domain and range vector spaces  in terms of the original graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spectral clustering we not find the eigenvectors of a graph (a graph is not a matrix) but the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the Laplacian matrix related to the adjacency matrix of the graph:

**graph => adjacency matrix => Laplacian matrix => eigenvalues (spectrum)**.

The adjacency matrix describes the "similarity" between two graph vertexs. In the most simple case (undirected unweighted simple graph), a value "1" in the matrix means two vertex joined by an edge, a value "0" means no edge between these vertex.

So, the space under the adjacency matrix is the space of connectivity, being row "i" of a column vector a measure of the connectivity with vertex "i". In other words, the adjacency and Laplacian matrix map from vertexs to vertex connectivity.

**Example**

Assume a simple graph with 3 vertex {1,2,3} and edges (1,2) and (2,3). The respective Laplacian matrix is:

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

a) vertex 1, than in vertex space is (1,0,0) maps to:

$$
A\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

if we analyze the product result, component by component, it means:

- vertex 1 is connected to 1 node.
- vertex 2 is connected to vertex 1
- vertex 3 is not connected to vertex 1.

b) the set of vertexs 1 and 2, that is represented in vertex space as (1,1,0), maps to:

$$
A\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

meaning that:

- vertex 1 is internal or external to the set {1,2}, not frontier (in this concrete case, it is internal: belongs to set and has no edge with any node out of the set).
- vertex 2 is a vertex in the set and connected to one vertex out of the set (internal frontier).
- vertex 3 is a vertex not in the set but connected to it (external frontier).

Finally, see what happens if multiply (inner/scalar product) previous result by the vertex vector again:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
A\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
= 1
$$

it gives the number of edges that connects the set of nodes {1,2} with the remainder graph.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer! I have one follow up question. As you have told, we see the Laplacian as a linear transformation from the vertex space to the connectivity space. Are vertex and connectivity spaces vector spaces? Do they have an algebra equivalent to closure properties(like + and scalar multiplication)? If yes, how are these properties defined?

Comment: @ManishKausikHariBaskar: yes, they are. Fiedler value and vector is an example of its application. The problem that surpasses my mathematical knowledge is the meaning of a vertex vector not-unary (component values different of 0 and 1), as the ones present in the eigenvectors of the Laplacian. Could be something to ask in math stack exchange.